# How do I load data to my table when my app starts?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to load data to a table on a separate fragment. I have my data in a text file then convert it into arrays, I have it working but I cant get it to work when trying to get it to work on startup. I think my problem is when I call the loadData method but I could be wrong. I am calling it inside the MainActivity.

The error I get is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Here is my method to load data:

```
public void loadData() {
    //Accounts
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myExternalFile = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/App_Folder/", "accounts.txt");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            accounts.add(strLine);
        }
        br.close();
        in.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
        String[] splitArray = accounts.get(i).split("//");

        String accountNameText = splitArray[0];
        String amountSavedText = splitArray[1];
        String goalText = splitArray[2];
        String percentText = splitArray[3];

        // get a reference for the TableLayout
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.accountTable);

        // create a new TableRow
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        TextView accountName = new TextView(this);
        accountName.setText(accountNameText);

        TextView amountSaved = new TextView(this);
        amountSaved.setText(amountSavedText);

        TextView accountGoal = new TextView(this);
        accountGoal.setText(goalText);

        TextView accountPercent = new TextView(this);
        accountPercent.setText(percentText);

        row.addView(accountName);
        row.addView(amountSaved);
        row.addView(accountGoal);
        row.addView(accountPercent);

        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your activity layout, check if there is a view with id **accountTable**

Comment: The table is in a separate layout file from the main layout. It is in a fragment

Comment: If you are trying to load a Fragment, you need to move this method there

Comment: How do I call the method within the fragment?

Comment: @GerryStraatsma I have added an answer showing you you can call the method andhow you can get the reference for the table layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed this way inside your Fragment (this code is just for sample):

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
 View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_view, container, false);

        //call loaddata

        loadData();
        return view;
    }
 public void loadData() {
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myExternalFile = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/App_Folder/", "accounts.txt");
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        accounts.add(strLine);
    }
    br.close();
    in.close();
    fis.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
    String[] splitArray = accounts.get(i).split("//");

    String accountNameText = splitArray[0];
    String amountSavedText = splitArray[1];
    String goalText = splitArray[2];
    String percentText = splitArray[3];

    // get a reference for the TableLayout, 
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.accountTable);

    // create a new TableRow
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());

    TextView accountName = new TextView(getContext());
    accountName.setText(accountNameText);

    TextView amountSaved = new TextView(getContext());
    amountSaved.setText(amountSavedText);

    TextView accountGoal = new TextView(getContext());
    accountGoal.setText(goalText);

    TextView accountPercent = new TextView(getContext());
    accountPercent.setText(percentText);

    row.addView(accountName);
    row.addView(amountSaved);
    row.addView(accountGoal);
    row.addView(accountPercent);

    table.addView(row);
}}}
```

Comment: in the `new TextView(this);` it gets underlined in red and if I hover over it says "TextView
(android.content.Context)
in TextView cannot be applied
to
(com.gstraatsma.gsfinancetracker.FragmentAccounts)"